# Start NFS server without UID and GID of Unix directory

Tags: windows, nfs, shared-folders, uid, gid

I'm trying to set up a NFS Server on Windows to map a folder of a Unix system connected to the same network.

The second step in the tutorial [How to set up a free NFS server on Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-free-nfs-server/) (sections 4 and 5) says to edit a registry by adding the UID and GID of the Unix directory, but that system is not accessible by me to get their IDs. Is there another way to finish the map the directory so I can place a file in it from Windows (maybe some wildcard values for the registers)?

Comment: You are asking on Unix & Linux to configure a Windows server. The only thing involving the Unix part: access to the Unix system, is not available. So what do you expect from here? If it were me I'd close it here and would try https://superuser.com instead or SF if you qualify: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: thank you, I will